# Is there a Django's inspectdb equivalent for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

I've used [Django's inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command in the past, which gives you models from an existing database.

Is there something equivalent for SQLAlchemy?

Comment: One of my user group people was discussing something like this. I'll ask on my mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [AutoCode project](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/).

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [sqlautocode](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Utilities/sqlautocode.html).

Answer (score 1):

For a Python3 compatible tool, check out [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen) or [flask-sqlacodegen](https://github.com/ksindi/flask-sqlacodegen) if you're looking for something that's actually maintained.